# How can I check what for permissions an AD-User have for an AD-Group?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I want to check with PowerShell if a user have Active Directory permissions ex. read or write for a specific group.

I found a way with `get-acl` to show me some information about the group and the user, but I'm not sure if I can and how to work with that further.

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55146121/how-to-use-powershell-to-find-group-memebership-to-include-members-of-nested-gro? Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072996/how-to-get-all-groups-that-a-user-is-a-member-of or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46295416/check-if-the-user-is-a-member-of-a-list-of-ad-groups or....If not: Please [edit]your question and clarify _if a user have Active Directory permissions for a specific group._

Comment: @OcasoProtal I though it was clear with "get-acl", sorry for that. I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be what you're looking for

```
$user = get-aduser "username" -Properties memberof
$userGroups = $user.MemberOf | Get-ADGroup
$group = Get-ADGroup "group to check"
$group.DistinguishedName -in $userGroups.DistinguishedName
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to check a specific user's AD rights over a specific group. Here's an example that will return all the individual rights assigned to a certain group.

```
Get-ADGroup "GroupToCheck" | Foreach-Object {
    foreach($dacl in Get-Acl AD:$($_.distinguishedname))
    {
        foreach($ace in $dacl.Access)
        {
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                "Group Name"          = $_.name
                "Group Owner"         = $dacl.owner
                ActiveDirectoryRights = $ace.ActiveDirectoryRights
                AccessControlType     = $ace.AccessControlType
                IdentityReference     = $ace.IdentityReference
            }
        }
    }
} -OutVariable AllRights
```

You could check if the user or a group the user is in has rights, group/filter the results by identity, etc.